# Validate XML entities in dropwizard

Tags: java, xml, validation, jersey, dropwizard

I have dropwizard 0.7.1 set up and the `@valid` annotation correctly works when using json and I get 422 errors in the HTTP responses.

If I change the resource and add jaxb bindings to use XML, the validation never kicks in.
Is it supported?

I tried manually instantiating a hibernate validator and it correctly detects the error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some MessageBodyProviders that wrap the JAXB ones and add Dropwizard validation: https://github.com/soulrebel/dropwizard-jaxb

I released the initial version. I will probably add some tests and publish it to Maven one day.

Answer (score 0):

I added this method in my user class and it validation works. In my junit test javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException is thrown wtih exact the given error message. I use DW 0.7.1!

```
    ...
    @ValidationMethod(message="user_name is null or empty")
    public boolean isUserName() {       
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user_name)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Only one problem still confuses me. I can not name the mehtod in my own way. It is important that if the class attibut is named user_name, then the validation method must be isUserName(). Tryed other method names, but then there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson also has support for Jaxb and Jackson annotated XML POJOs. You can also check an example I write in https://github.com/yunspace/dropwizard-xml which extends off  JacksonJaxbXMLProvider

Comment: That was my initial solution (and also served as inspiration), but I found that Jackson is not JAXB (which is on by default without validation in dropwizard) and a few things broke.

Comment: Jackson should support JAXB annotations by defining the appropriate introspectors: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations Haven't tried this myself either, will probably write some tests in my library later.